# Getting all the users from Domain Users using python ldap

Tags: python-2.7, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I am trying to retrieve all the users in the Domain Users group using python ldap but it just returns an empty list.

Here is my sample code:

```
context.search_ext_s('CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(&(objectclass=user)(|(primaryGroupID=513)(memberOf=CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com)))')
```

Every other piece of code seems to be working fine like getting groups and getting members from other groups. Only the Domain User group doesn't give out any results.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try droping the primaryGroupID from the filter.

Comment: Something like `context.search_ext_s('CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(&(objectclass=user)(|(primaryGroupID=513)(memberOf=CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com)))')` perhaps? Primary group id shouldn't be an issue since you are using or.